# if/else statement to only run if a match has been found question

Tags: python, arrays, regex

I've been trying to figure this out for a bit now, but I am at a loss. I've tried looking around for a solution in other boards and posts on here as well, but not really anything that I could find covers what I am looking for.

I am writing a script to parse JavaScript line by line and store the variable names found in an array. Due to how Javascript can be formatted I constructed a series of OR statements with this regex that pulls everything that I need.

`r"var\s(.*?)\s\=\s|var\s(.*?)\=|var\s(.*?)\=\s|var\s(.*?)\s\=|var\s(.*?)\;"`

This matches everything up to 5 groups.

The issue I am having is that I want certain code to run if a certain match group is found (1-5).

This is what I have so far. I read about doing "is not None" to check for an empty match that is not found, but that is not working in my case.

How can I go about doing this?

**Current Code snippet:**

```py
for line in Converted_Text.splitlines():
    
    VarName_Regex = r"var\s(.*?)\s\=\s|var\s(.*?)\=|var\s(.*?)\=\s|var\s(.*?)\s\=|var\s(.*?)\;"
    VarName_Match = re.search(VarName_Regex, line, re.MULTILINE)
    

    if VarName_Match.group(1) is not None:
        VarName = VarName_Match.group(1)
    elif VarName_Match.group(2) is not None:
        VarName = VarName_Match.group(2) 
    elif VarName_Match.group(3) is not None:
        VarName = VarName_Match.group(3)
    elif VarName_Match.group(4) is not None:
        VarName = VarName_Match.group(4)
    elif VarName_Match.group(5) is not None:
        VarName = VarName_Match.group(5)
```

**Testing code:**

```js
var array=['cat','food','bowl'];

"The array[0] wants array[1]";
"Please put array[1] in her array[2].";

var blah, joke, meh;

var num1= 1;
var num2 =2;
var sum = num1+num2;
var blah, meh;

window.print(sum);

var falsenum = '';
```

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Is it issuing an error message? What result do you expect from the code you've shown?

Comment: You also need to check `if VarName_Match is not None:`. If none of the alternatives matched, `re.search()` returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if VarName_Match.group(1):
   VarName = VarName_Match.group(1)
elif VarName_Match.group(2):
   VarName = VarName_Match.group(2)
elif VarName_Match.group(3):
   VarName = VarName_Match.group(3)
elif VarName_Match.group(4):
   VarName = VarName_Match.group(4)
elif VarName_Match.group(5):
   VarName = VarName_Match.group(5)
else:
   VarName = None
```